# How to pass datas that I get through getServerSideProps to all pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-state

I want to use color that I get through getServerSideProps(different colors/each customers) in all pages.

So what I was going to do were:
(1)useState: Is there any ways to get datas through getServerSideProps and set the data as useState?
(2)_app.js: getServerSideProps doesn't work on _app.js.

I'm using Next.js. Thank you.

Comment: You can either use `getInitialProps` in `_app`, or use `getServerSideProps` on all pages.

Comment: I get a color data throught getInitialProps in _app. but how can I pass this date to each components like buttons and headers?

Comment: What you return from `getInitialProps` will be available in the custom app `pageProps`. You can then pass those down to your page components and other components (or use React context if you'd prefer). See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app.